# XSLTProcessor : operation unsecure?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xslt

I am using the XSLTProcessor class to transform an XML file I retrieve via AJAX from the same server, same protocol. The XSL file used to translate is hard-coded as a string inline and transformed into an XML via jQuery's $.parseXML().

Then I do this:

```
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl); // created inline via jQuery
result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml); // xml retrieved via AJAX
```

Chrome fails silently. Firefox gives me this message on the third line:

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Any ideas why this is a security issue? This page I am running the javascript on and the XML file I am AJAXing are from the same domain, both HTTPS. Do I have to pull the XSL file from the server as well instead of writing it out inline?

EDIT:
Just to clarify I don't have access to server-side code.

I'm literally just using the XSL to rename a couple of elements. I've tried pulling it from the same server path as the XML instead of writing it out inline, same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xelement">
        <element><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xsub-element">
        <sub-element><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></sub-element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**If there is an easy way to rename XML elements without using XSL I'll gladly use that instead. My goal is to rename the elements, not necessarily to get XSL working.**

Comment: Does the XSLT perhaps use the `document` function to load XML from a different origin?

Comment: Can you show us your XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not XSLT related, but content related. The way you retrieve data to your page.

Your content is not from the same domain.
The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin.

Internet Explorer has two major exceptions when it comes to same origin policy

**Trust Zones**:

if both domains are in highly trusted zone e.g, corporate domains, then the same origin limitations are not applied

**Port**:

IE doesn't include port into Same Origin components, therefore http://company.com:81/index.html and http://company.com/index.html are considered from same origin and no restrictions are applied.

Comment: The content is from the same domain. Both the XML and XSL are stored on the same server, and the content page with the javascript is also coming from that server all under the same domain. I wish the solution was something this simple.

Comment: please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy as http to https won't work, check everything from Same Origin Policy. I'm pretty sure it's this issue you are having.

Comment: It definitely sounds like the issue I'm having, but I don't see any same doman conflicts. Everything is pulled from https, our server doesn't even allow http connections.

Comment: I would suggest by trying a simple example from https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ replace line 14 in this example with your ajax call for the XML data.